# What should I use <ng-template> or *ngIf to display dynamic component?

Tags: angular, architecture

Let's say that I have 2 components that will be displayed conditionaly.
We can do this in 2 ways:

HTML

```
<div>
   <first-component *ngIf="shouldBeDisplayedFirst()"></first-component>
   <second-component *ngIf="shouldBeDisplayedSecond()"></second-component>
</div>
```

Main component

```
shouldBeDisplayedFirst(){
   if(Something === true) {
      return true;
   }
}

shouldBeDisplayedSecond(){
   if(SomethingElse === true) {
      return true;
   }
}
```

It works and it's short.

But we can do this with using `<ng-template>` as well

HTML

```
<ng-template #myContainer><ng-template>
```

Main component

```
@ViewChild('myContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) myContainer: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

ngOnInit() {
   loadCorrectComponent();
}

loadCorrectComponent() {
   let containerFactory = null;

   if (Something) {
      containerFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(firstComponent);
   } else if (SomethingElse) {
      containerFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(secondComponent);
   }

   this.myContainer.createComponent(containerFactory);
}
// and we have to declare these components to entryComponents in MainModule
```

As you can see first solution is easier to implement, but is it appropriate solution? Or in such a case I should do it in second way? Is there any noticable diffrence between these solutions?

Comment: I love this question. It shows insight and I almost suspect that you are asking for other reasons than to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is less code, easier to read, easier to maintain, and I would recommend it in most situations.

The only reason that I'd do it the second way is if I had a large number of conditional components. For instance, I built a form builder component that builds a form from a JSON description, and needed to support a wide variety of form components. There, it made sense to dynamically instantiate the components.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two solutions that solves the same problem, I would choose the one that is easier to read, understand and maintain.

Also, since we are using Angular, one should avoid code that manipulates or "knows about" its template as much as possible. This is more often true for application level components than micro level components (buttons, lists and so on).

If you are making a reusable library, and do not know what components may be in your template, the latter code sample may be necessary. A good example is why Angular has two ways of creating forms.